# Static version of Joomla site with wget

Tags: joomla, static, wget

I need to create a static version of a Joomla website. I'm using wget to download files. But the downloaded files have a base url that point to the live site.

If I remove the  tag, then the local files become a mess, since references to css, javascript etc. start with a slash and Chrome errors with "Not allowed to load local resource"

Here some source code from the downloaded site:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home - My Site</title>
<link href="/templates/mytemplate/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="/templates/mytemplate/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/templates/mytemplate/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/templates/mytemplate/js/template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to create a good local static copy of a site? What setting am I maybe missing in wget?

Answer (score 1):

To make a really static copy of a site, you need to specify both `-k` (`--convert-links`) and `-p` (`--page-requisites`):

```
$ cd <target-dir>
$ wget -k -p http://www.example.com
$ cd www.example.com
$ firefox index.html
```

This is not Joomla specific, though.

Comment: Yes, it's the -k option. I've figured out that this is the wget setting to use: 
`wget -r -l 10 -k -p -t 5 -nc -E -X /folder1,/folder2/ -w 5 http://www.example.com`